# Spring Boot test: how to partially mock a service with AOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, testcontainers

I'm trying to test a Spring Boot service that depends on both a repository and another service. I'm using TestContainers to verify that the service interacts correctly with the repository. However, I need to mock the other service in order to provide the test data that will be used. The service method in question needs to be transactional.

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
  private MyRepository myRepository; // This needs to be a real repository
  private OtherService otherService; // This needs to be mocked

  @Autowired
  public MyService(MyRepository myRepository, OtherService otherService) {...}

  @Transactional
  public void methodToTest() {
    // Get (mock) data from otherService, and interact with (real) myRepository
  }
}
```

I can get it working in my test by manually creating the service with its dependencies. However, the resulting object is just a POJO that has not been enhanced by Spring to be `Transactional`:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {TestContainersConfig.class})
public class MyServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  MyRepository myRepository;
  OtherService otherService;
  MyService myService;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    otherService = Mockito.mock(OtherService.class);
    // This works, except that the object is a POJO and so @Transactional doesn't work
    myService = new MyService(myRepository, otherService);
  }

  @Test
  @Transactional
  void testMethodToTest() {
    // Provide mock data
    when(otherSerivce.something()).thenReturn(...);

    // Run the test
    myService.methodToTest();

    // Would like to remove these lines: myService should already do it
    TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
    TestTransaction.end();

    // assertions...
  }
}
```

How can I get Spring to enhance the test `MyService` instance so that `methodToTest` will handle the transaction?

Comment: Which is exactly use usecase for `@MockBean`.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you elaborate? Should MyService or OtherService be a MockBean? I've tried using a test configuration class that provides the mock OtherService, but then I wasn't able to autowire MyService in the test...

Comment: What do you think? What do you want to mock needs to be a mock, so the `OtherService` in this case. Basically you are working around SPring Boot instead of embracing it.

Comment: This article on [@Mock vs. @MockBean](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/) can shed some light on this.